# Plotly Sankey Diagram, aligning nodes

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

I created a Sankey diagram using plotly (python) and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, some links overlap, but this plot can be easily changed (manually) to this:

[image]

I think the overlapping result comes from the 3rd column of nodes being centered on Y. Is there a way for me to align the 3rd column to the top (or bottom) to fix this problem? (or any other fix is also welcome of course)

The only thing I've found is setting x and y for nodes manually, but I seem to not be able to only set the y, and this also would involve calculating all those coordinates.

Thank you for the help!

Edit: My code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

sources = [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 8, 23, 23, 23, 30, 17, 5, 12, 20, 20, 23, 18, 18, 18, 18, 23, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 23, 16, 16, 23]
targets = [7, 13, 6, 21, 1, 2, 15, 23, 23, 32, 25, 19, 23, 23, 23, 23, 27, 22, 20, 31, 4, 0, 3, 18, 11, 26, 9, 14, 28, 33, 29, 10, 16]
values = [50.0, 1542.78, 287.44, 2619.76, 1583.26, 722.1, 5133.69, 6544.0, 2563.35, 6476.59, 4314.0, 82.87, 650.0, 1773.68, 16723.0, 32297.7, 81.64, 266.92, 348.56, 388.57, 743.2, 5403.24, 5821.52, 12356.53, 12905.68, 316.12, 497.68, 354.42, 3830.44, 17904.34, 175.95, 1224.46, 1400.41]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
node = dict(
  pad = 5,
  thickness = 10,
  line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
  label = list(range(len(values))),
  color = "blue"
),
link = dict(
  source = sources,
  target = targets,
  value  = values
))])

fig.update_layout(title_text=
"Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=8)
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you used to produce this behavior?

Comment: Yes, sorry, added a minimal example that gives the same diagram as I've shown

Comment: No worries - that's perfect! I will have a look if someone doesn't answer before me

Comment: @DerekO So no solution found then I assume?

Comment: I am not an expert on Plotly sankey diagrams, but I couldn't come up with anything...

Answer (score 0):

There's [an open issue on github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1732) that **both** x and y positions have to be set in order for manual positioning to work. Does manually adding y coordinates along with x coordinates address your problem?

In general there [other issues with sankey sorting](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4373) as well.

I have been working with problems in this area only in plotly.R so I'm afraid I can't offer specific python suggestions to modify your code.

If you're also looking for suggestions about calculating the coordinates manually, you can calculate this as

`1 - (cumulative_sum_of_higher_nodes + current_node_size/2)`

or

`1 - (cumulative_sum_of_all_nodes_including_current_node - current_node_size/2)`

assuming y = 0 is at the bottom of the plot area.